# Recursion principle proof doubt

Tags: proof-explanation, set-theory

I'm reading "Classic Set Theory: For Guided Independent Study" and I'm trying to understand the proof of the recursion principle (I will just upload a picture since it's very long, you don't need to read it all I guess, but maybe it can help to answer the question, the part I don't understand is highlighted in yellow):
[image][image][image]

I don't understand how if $m∈n$, then $m∩n=m$. If for example $m=\{1,2,3\}$, and 
we need $m∈n$, this means that $n$ has to be at least of the form $n=\{\{1,2,3\},...\}$ and if $m∩n$ has to be equal to $m$ that means some of the elements of $n$ have to be $1,2,3$, but who tells us that they are? how is this implied from $m∈n$? Could you guys help me please? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For starters, $m$ cannot be $\{1,2,3\}$, since that isn’t an element of $\Bbb N$. What you’re missing here is the actual definition of $\Bbb N$, whose elements are built up from $0$ by repeated applications of the successor operation $x^+=x\cup\{x\}$.

Your $\Bbb N$ contains $0$, $1=0^+=0\cup\{0\}=\{0\}$ (since by definition $0=\varnothing$),

$$2=1^+=1\cup\{1\}=\{0\}\cup\{\{0\}\}=\{0,\{0\}\}\;,$$

$$3=2^+=2\cup\{2\}=\{0,\{0\}\}\cup\{\{0,\{0\}\}\}=\big\{0,\{0\},\{0,\{0\}\}\big\}\;,$$

and so on. This definition is neatly designed so that for each $n\in\Bbb N$, $n=\{k\in\Bbb N:k<n\}$: each member of $\Bbb N$ **is** the set of smaller members of $\Bbb N$.

Now suppose that $m\in n$. This means that $m<n$, so

$$m=\{k\in\Bbb N:k<m\}\subseteq\{k\in\Bbb N:k<n\}=n\;:$$

$m$ is a subset of $n$ as well as an element of $n$. And of course it’s always true that if $A\subseteq B$, then $A\cap B=A$, so $m\cap n=m$.

Comment: Just to be precise (and give the standard argument for existence of $\mathbb N$ from set theory) I would add, that this construction usually starts with $0=\emptyset$, as is also written in a sidenote above.

Comment: @Benjamin: Huh. I apparently accidentally omitted the $0\cup\{0\}$ step when I typed it; thanks for catching that.

Comment: Ooh i didnt think about it! thank you!

Comment: One more question though, right below that part it says: $g_0⊆g_1⊆g_2⊆...⊆g_n⊆g_(n^+)⊆...$ and then it defines $f$ to be the union of all these sets. Isn't this equivalent to saying that $f$ is the "largest" of all these sets? since $A⊆B$ iff $A∪B=B$?

Comment: @AndreaBurgio: It would be, if the chain were finite. Here, though, it’s not, because all of those inclusions are actually proper: $g_0\subsetneqq g_1\subsetneqq g_2\subsetneqq\ldots\;.$ It’s like letting $I_0=\{0\}$, $I_1=[-1,1]$, $I_2=[-2,2]$, and in general $I_n=[-n,n]$: then $I_0\subseteq I_1\subseteq I_2\subseteq\ldots\;,$, but $\bigcup_nI_n=\Bbb R$, a set bigger than all of them. Similarly, your $g$ is a set bigger than all of the sets $g_n$: it’s infinite, and they are all finite.